# Make Distinct Reccuring Value In Text

Tags: regex, distinct, distinct-values, regexp-substr, listagg

I have a problem to make distinct in a text. I have a table column separated semi column in my oracle database. It has recurring values and ı want them distinct. For example;

```
with s (ID, ID_NAME) as (
select 1, 'GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE WEST,GEORGE WEST,GEORGE MICHAEL' from dual union all    
select 2, 'THOMAS EDISON,THOMAS COOK,THOMAS EDISON' from dual   
) 
SELECT * FROM S ;
```

The result:

```
[ID  ID_NAME
1   GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE WEST,GEORGE WEST,GEORGE MICHAEL
2   THOMAS EDISON,THOMAS COOK,THOMAS EDISON][1]
```

BUT I want distinct values in text.

```
1 GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE WEST,GEORGE MICHAEL
2 THOMAS EDISON,THOMAS COOK,THOMAS EDISON
```

As you see in 1st line I don't want recurring values. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

After setting up a CTE with test data, create another CTE (tbl_parsed) with rows created by traversing the strings using connect by, creating a row for each element.  Lastly select distinct from that and put it back together with listagg.

```
with s(ID, ID_NAME) as (
select 1, 'GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE JOHN,GEORGE WEST,GEORGE WEST,GEORGE MICHAEL' from dual union all    
select 2, 'THOMAS EDISON,THOMAS COOK,THOMAS EDISON' from dual   
),
tbl_parsed(id, element, name) as (
  select id, level element, regexp_substr(ID_NAME, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, null, 1)
  from s
  connect by level <= regexp_count(ID_NAME, ',')+1
    and prior id = id
    and prior sys_guid() is not null 
)
--select * from tbl_parsed;
SELECT id, listagg(name, ',') within group (order by id) sorted
FROM (select distinct id, name from tbl_parsed)
group by id;
```